# PHP put several arrays in one separated by ","

Tags: php, arrays, html, multidimensional-array

I have some arrays extracted from a XML-file. These are in

```
$array0 = (.......)
$array1 = (.......)
...
$arrayN = (.......)
```

Now I need a single array with all arrays in it separated by "," as

```
$masterArray = array($array0,
                     $array1,
                  ...
                     $arrayN)
```

I tried

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < N; $i++) {
$masterArray = $masterArray + $array[$i];
}
```

with no result. I tried array_merge but this will give one

```
$masterArray(......................all items of all $arrays.....)
```

How can I do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your exact definition of what you got and what you want the routine should be:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < N; $i++) $masterArray[] = ${'array'.$i};
```

Not much to explain here. You make a new entry in an array with `$variable[] = <entry>;` and you access your numbered array with a variable variable, see:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Thanks - but I got in my masterArray N-times all arrays. Using it with $i < 1 instead of $i < N it works perfect.

Answer (score 5):

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < N; $i++) {
    $temp = "array".$i;
    $masterArray[$i] = ${$temp};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wont to create a multi dimension array:

```
$masterArray = array();
$masterArray[] = $array0;
$masterArray[] = $array1;
...
$masterArray[] = $arrayN;
```

this will in all arrays as element of the MasterArray:

```
$masterArray[0=>(....),1=>(....), ...];
```

Then access it like this:

```
$arr1_key1 = $masterArray[1]['key1'] ; //$array1['key1'];
```

You can add specific keys if you wont:

```
$masterArray['arr1'] = $array1;
$arr1_key1 = $masterArray['arr1']['key1'] ; //$array1['key1']
```

In general [read](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html) some more to get better understanding on how to work with arrays ;)

Comment: Thanks, no I needed really each array "behind" the other. Reading yes, I do. But I have to start practical too, otherwise the reading is "for nothing" and forgotten till I need the knowledge. So I want to code for a real use and have to stop by a real problem to solve it and understanding why. But I continue in reading, no question.